# Given Latitude, Longitude, and Elevation, how to illustrate a three-dimensional path?

Tags: graphics3d, geography

I've extracted detailed path information from a .FIT file and would like to plot this in three dimensions. I assumed GeoPositionXYZ[] would be useful, and have translated the data into a list that looks like this . . .

```
allGeoPoints={GeoPositionXYZ[{-11.6394(*latitude*), 166.948 (*longitude*), 7.2(*altitude, in meters*)}], 
 GeoPositionXYZ[{-11.6394, 166.948, 7.2}], 
 GeoPositionXYZ[{-11.6394, 166.948, 7.2}] . . . etc.
}
```

I had thought `GeoGraphics[allGeoPoints]` would get me at least partway there, but it seems to be able to do nothing with the data, rendering instead a map of my current location.

What am I missing?

Comment: maybe `GeoGraphics[Point@GeoPosition@allGeoPoints,GeoRange -> "World", GeoProjection -> "LambertAzimuthal"]  `?

Comment: Update: Solved it for 2D -- I should have been using GeoPosition[] instead of GeoPositionXYZ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say that list `data` contains triples of {latitude,longitude,altitude}. One possible visualisation uses `ListPointPlot3D` as follows.

```
ListPointPlot3D[
   data,
   Filling -> Bottom, BoxRatios -> {Automatic, Automatic, 0.04},
   RotationAction -> "Clip",
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow", 2.5 (#3 - 0.6)] &)]
```

[image: 3D path]

Comment: Ah -- this works so long as I strip the `GeoPosition` head from my points, and adjust the vertical scaling appropriately. Thus, `ListPointPlot3D[allGeoPoints3D[[All, 1]], Filling -> Bottom, 
 BoxRatios -> {Automatic, Automatic, .01}, RotationAction -> "Clip", 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow", 2.5 (#3 - 0.6)] &)]` for my test data. Thanks!